# Windows 10 UI or display issue with weird flashes and particles

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS laptop (Windows 10) here that has a weird problem I can't get fixed. The screen renders weird shapes, mainly when opening Windows menus. When just browsing in Chrome it's alright 90% of the time.

I can't find anyone online with the same issue so either it doesn't exist anywhere else or I can't find the right name to describe it. So here is a photo:

[image]

These things move around and flash, but seem to made up from parts of what's on the screen.

When booting into safe mode, they are not around.
I tried: rebooting, re-installing display driver, running anti virus scans.

If anyone knows what this is called or how to fix it, please let me know! :)

Comment: update the GPU drivers (Intel HD, nVIDIA or AMD)

Answer (score 0):

You have done the good test: *When booting into safe mode, they are not around.*
It seems that driver has trouble.

Reinstall display driver is not enough, please update system to the latest build at first, current version is 10563.138(Windows 10 1703 version)
Then, open device manager to update driver software, especially graphics adapter and chipset.

After these, go to System Properties/Advanced tab/Performance/Settings, choose Adjust for best appearance.

Finally, reboot computer in the clean boot mode. If still no help, create a new account to check

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try it this weekend when I'm around my parents again (it's their laptop). I'll keep you posted!